# MS Word for Mac: changing smart quote types

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, smart-quotes

In MS Word for Mac (as in MS Word for Windows), there is an option to use so-called ‘smart quotes’, which automatically changes 'straight quotes' into ‘curly ones’. This in itself is a good thing, and it works fine in English.

In some other languages, however, the ‘smart’ quotes are not so smart—in fact, they’re downright incorrect. I’m currently editing a long document which is written in Danish, with smart quotes turned off. The simplest way to convert all straight quotes to curly ones is to just do a replace-all with smart quotes turned on, changing single and double quotes to identical values.

That won’t work here, though, because for Danish, Word has, in its infinite wisdom, decided that ‘smart’ quotes should be unpaired—that is, they should be ’smart quotes’ and ”smart quotes”, rather than ‘smart quotes’ and “smart quotes”. Moreover, in the style that the book this is for uses, double quotes should be »inwards-facing chevrons«.

In programs like InDesign, you can set your preferred style of quotes for each individual language: they’re essentially based on dictionary lookups stored somewhere on your hard drive, made accessible through the GUI. This doesn’t seem to be the case for MS Word, at least not as far as the GUI is concerned.

#### Is there any way of manually changing what ‘smart quotes’ means for a given language?

(I don’t believe there’s anything version-specific about this, except perhaps the location of whatever file I should be modifying, but I’m using Word 2016 for Mac, currently version 15.31.)